# How to pass a variable from onClicListener to dbHandler

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a list with onItemClickListener. In list are date and place.
I would like to pass the place (when is clicked) to database handler and then in new activity get all data with same place.

I'm not quite good in android so I'm asking is it possible to do that? And how to pass this variable with place name into dbHandler?

here is my onItemClickListener

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_listview);

    mainListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewItem);

    dbHandler = new LogsDBHandler(this);
    ArrayList<Logs> logsList = dbHandler.getAllLogsGroupedByPlace();
    listAdapter = new LogsByPlaceAdapter(logsList);
    mainListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(DisplayLogsByPlace.this, LogsList.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

private class LogsByPlaceAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Logs> logsList;

    public LogsByPlaceAdapter(List<Logs> logsList) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(DisplayLogsByPlace.this);
        this.logsList = logsList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return logsList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return logsList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return logsList.get(position).getId();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_display_logs_by_place, parent, false);
        }

        Logs log = logsList.get(position);
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textShowDate)).setText(log.getCreatedAt().toString());
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textShowPlace)).setText(log.getPlace());
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

And this is my dbHandler in which I would call this variable

```
public ArrayList<Logs> getAllLogsWithSamePlace(String place) {
        ArrayList<Logs> logPlaceList = new ArrayList<Logs>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_LOGS + " WHERE " + KEY_PLACE + "=" + place;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
           ...
        }
        return  logPlaceList;
    }
```

Comment: onItemClickListener pass place value with intent and in SecondActivity first get value from intent and call dbHandler methos to get getAllLogsWithSamePlace data

Comment: What is your Adapter look like?? What is AdapterView<?> look like?? Does it have any object instead of Generics??

Comment: I have just updated activity with adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,        long id) {

    // if your method is static
    ArrayList<String> array = dbHandler.getAllLogsWithSamePlace(place);
    // if not you shoud initialize the dbhandler

    Intent intent = new Intent(DisplayLogsByPlace.this, LogsList.class);

    intent.putArrayListExtra("sameplaceArray", array);

    startActivity(intent);
    }
});


    public ArrayList<Logs> getAllLogsWithSamePlace(String place) {
    ArrayList<Logs> logPlaceList = new ArrayList<Logs>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_LOGS + " WHERE " +    KEY_PLACE + "=" + place;


    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
       ...
    }
    return  logPlaceList;
}
}
```

Comment: It's not quite what I need.  This mine place is column in DB. and in list view I grouped it by place. So i need somehow to pass this place when it is clicked in activity to SqlQuery in dbHandler `String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_LOGS + " WHERE " + KEY_PLACE + "=" + place;`

Comment: I didn't understand what you said, when you call getAllLogs... method you automatically passed the place value to the dbhandler. could you explain more what you need

Comment: Thank you. Didn't know that automatically passes the value to dbHandler. i created like this
`mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
   ArrayList<Logs> placeValue = dbHandler.getAllLogsWithSamePlace(place);

Intent intent = new Intent(DisplayLogsByPlace.this, LogsList.class);
intent.putExtra("keyPlace", placeValue);
 startActivity(intent);
 }
 });`
don't know why but error is (place)?

Comment: because you have to define the specific place first like "Iran" then pass it to the method

Comment: Hm.. but i need to get that place when I clickOnListItem if you know what i mean?

Comment: you can get it by  String place = logsList.get(position).getplace(); just like when you populate your listview at first. I recommend you to watch more tutorials on internet.

Answer (score 0):

```
mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
   Intent intent = new Intent(DisplayLogsByPlace.this, LogsList.class);
   intent.putExtra("keyword","PlaceValue");
   startActivity(intent);
   }
});
```

After that In `SecondActivity` get intent value like this

```
String place=getIntent().getExtra().getString("keyword");
```

then after call dbHandler function to get data

Comment: That is good, but not what I need. This mine place is column in DB. and in list view I grouped it by place. So i need somehow to pass this place when it is clicked in activity to SqlQuery in dbHandler ( `String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_LOGS + " WHERE " + KEY_PLACE + "=" + place;`)